# Haskell Quine: "ap" Monad

Tags: haskell, monads, quine

What is the proper way to use the "ap" monad in Haskell? I want to do something similar to this:

```
main = (putStr . ap (++) show) "main = (putStr . ap (++) show) "
```

but I get the error "Not in scope: 'ap'."

Using "import Control.Monad" does nothing.
And I have tried giving it

```
"ap :: Monad m => m (a -> b) -> m a -> m b"
```

then I get "The type signature for `ap' lacks an accompanying binding"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Importing `Control.Monad` should give you `ap`. However, in all but the most recent versions of GHC (7.6.1 and newer), you'll also need to import `Control.Monad.Instances` to use the monad instance for functions.

Alternatively, you can import `Control.Applicative` which gives you the `<*>` operator, which is `ap` generalized to `Applicative`, as well as the necessary instances to use it with functions.

Comment: And alternatively, if we want to avoid imports, instead of importing either module we can just use `(\f g x -> f x (g x))` (the S combinator, which `(<*>)` and `ap` are type class-generic versions thereof).

Comment: @sacundim: Who would redefine a standard library function just to "avoid imports"? I mean, you will need imports anyway for any non-trivial programs

Comment: @NiklasB.: possibly somebody trying to write a Quine program, like GossJ is trying to do. I did not work out how the original program would need to be modified to incorporate the import, because inlining the S combinator just works right away.

Comment: @sacundim: Should have paid more attention to the question, sorry for my useless comment :)